# Pub-Sub model for interacting between Web API applications

Tags: asp.net, apache-kafka, signalr, publish-subscribe

We have an application which has set of APIs developed in .NET CORE and UI which consume these APIs developed in Angular(both are independent projects) . Both are hosted on azure app service.

1. WebAPI integrates with 3rd Party APIs. Some of those transactional
   APIs are very time consuming, so we want to have fire and forget way
   of calling those and have them notified when they end.
2. Once our API receives the response from 3rd party, we want that be notified to UI

So we want some messaging or Pub-Sub mechanism to achieve this

I am in consideration of SignalR and Kafka.

From the documents that I red about SignalR it seems that it can be used between  API -client, so I can use this for 2nd scenario.
Can SignalR be used between 2 APIs?

Coming to Kakfa , it seems to be good one for high end data streaming which I consider as over-engineering for our requirement.

Our application will be on both Azure and on-prem so we also went through Azure service bus but there is limit on Message length and cost seem to be problem for us.

So I want to know if there are any ways I can have this communication eased between 2 WebAPIs application?

Comment: 1) Does SignalR require your client and server to be directly connected? If one API is down, what happens to the requests? 2) Kafka is not a "web technology". Your Asp.net code would still need to figure out how to direct events to some frontend client, which is generally what websockets or SSE are for 3) sounds like you just need a webhook, not pubsub

Comment: When you say kafka is not a web technology, that means can it not be used between 2 API applications? can I not host it separately and have those 2 application send and receive messages? SignalR uses websocket , can that be used? I am new to this topic so these may be some naïve questions, but thank you for the reply!

Comment: Kafka doesn't have any features (out of the box) for doing anything with your Angular components. Therefore, it's not web oriented. You'll need to understand the Angular code is running in a end user browser, not in the same server as the ASP. NET code, so although Kafka can send events between your backend, so could literally any other RPC or message queue. If you need to send dynamic server events to the frontend, you'll need something that supports Websockets, at least, yes.

Comment: Ok so between API and angular a websocket like SignalR could work... how about between 2 Web APIs? does SignalR still holds good .i.e., can I consider another web API as client and push the notification? I mean, Does client have to be web browser or UI or can it be another API in ASP .NET ?

Comment: For clarity "Web API" doesn't mean anything to me personally. You have an HTTP server... You can use HTTP requests between them (or any other TCP methods via other ports/protocols). That being said, a browser is acting as an HTTP client and renderer, so you can still use external HTTP clients such as `curl` or PostMan to interact with them... I've not used SignalR to know its limitations or features.

Comment: Sure @OneCricketeer, Thank you for clarifying the doubts!